# Why throw away a dereferencing value in GO waitgroup.wait()?

Tags: go

In the package 'waitgroup' the method Wait() seems to throw away a dereference to  'statep' with the comment "//trigger nil deref early"

Edit*
Why do we trigger a nil deref early?

```
func (wg *WaitGroup) Wait() {
    statep, semap := wg.state()
    if race.Enabled {
        _ = *statep // trigger nil deref early
        race.Disable()
    }
```

Comment: Race detection isn't precise or instantaneous. If the standard library has an opportunity to detect it "early" and not wait for future calls, then that is what it is doing here

Answer (score 0):

The statement `_ = *statep` triggers a nil pointer panic when `statep` is nil.

The purpose of the statement is to simplify the later code in the function. The call to race.Disable() must be balanced with a call to race.Enable(). The code does not need to consider the possibility of a nil pointer panic when balancing the calls.